Set field visibility not working for experience cloud user
I have set field visibility set to show 3 new fields when Product = Product 1
Am I missing a setting in the experience builder somewhere?
I've got the pages assigned to the app and the profiles including the test profile the experience cloud creates
When I log in as an experience user and set Product to Product 1, the fields that are supposed to show do not show. They have visibility and edit rights to these fields, and it works fine for our internal users.
